# How do I resize UITextview when the Keyboard shows up in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios7, keyboard-events

It appears the old way of doing this in iOS 6 has been broken by Apple. Can anyone guide me right? I looked up apple's developer library and all I got was "It's simpler to embed in a ScrollView" which I find to be rather ridiculous and unnecessary. Has anyone found a way to get this done yet?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (kbSize.width > kbSize.height ? kbSize.height : kbSize.width), 0);
    self.mainTextView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.mainTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

This doesn't work for me. The problem I have is the textview doesnt seem to get resized at runtime and the Keyboard hides the text that at the lower part of the screen. Is there something wrong with my code or this approach?

Comment: Can you explain "It appears the old way of doing this in iOS 6 has been broken by Apple"?

Comment: Question duly edited :D

Comment: You're still not explaining the problem.  Is it that `keyboardWasShown:` is not called, that `kbSize` is `(0, 0)`, that setting `contentInset` suddenly places the top left corner of the text view under the navigation bar?  What's happening?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to get any other information?  Is the method called?  What is the value of `kbSize`?

Comment: I get a value of 216.00000 for kbSize.height, So I'm sure the method gets called.

Comment: In that case, there's no reason the following shouldn't trigger any visual behavior, unless `mainTextView` is `nil`.

Comment: I see.. Do you mind running that snippet in a dummy project if you have Xcode 5? I'd like to know if it's not just xcode acting up with some "hidden issues" again. Thanks

Comment: I did it the old way, with scrollViews, in iOS 6. Recommended. :)

Comment: You embedded the textview in a scrollview? then used the contentInset technique??

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem in migrating my code.  The problem is that you are using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Its a before-animation versus after-animation thing.

The upgrade to iOS7.0 has made the code work now as the documentation says it should, but that means also they have introduced a behaviour break.

Answer (score 1):

did you remember to register the notifications in viewdidLoad? (and don't forget to remove them in dealloc)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:
         UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:
         UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

there is a UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification that you can use to then modify your textview.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm referring to the keyboard notifications route?

Comment: have you verified that the old way is a deprecated method?

Comment: Well< I have no formal way of verifying that but I've been told it no longer works in iOS 7. If you can confirm otherwise I'd be happy to hear that

Comment: if you look through the header files and don't see it or there is documentation in the header that says it's gone. then it's gone.